# Opinions on Payment Integration Within App...?

Tags: transaction

I'd like some opinions on this possible integration of Cardano payments on my native iOS app. Native as in it runs and can store information on the device. So Apple would pretty much be behind the security from that point on if I store information on the phone.

1. User enters Daedalus private key in my app and stored on device, never touching my server
2. User enters Daedalus passphrase in my app and stored on device, never touching my server
3. Before sending their order to my server, they sign it on device with Ed25519(universal Cardano signing algorithm?)
4. I can now pass the value from number 3 and go ahead with my transaction where I process it in my server using cardano-cli/cardano-wallet?

Comment: Sounds like you want to build your own wallet app, which is certainly possible. If you just want to use ADA payments in your app, it might be better to let the users pay to one of your addresses without entering their private key in your app.